# Remap 3D function onto a plane?

Tags: calculus, vectors, scalar-fields

I'm working on a design project in nTopology which is an implicit representation design software. So geometry objects are represented as implicit fields defined by continuous functions.

Bodies are represented by scalar distance fields. Boundaries of objects are zero, interiors of objects are negative, and fields are positive outside of bodies. What I'm trying to is take a "slice" of a 3D field on a plane defined by a normal vector and an origin point.

Let say the field is a function of unknown form:
$$
f(x, y, z)
$$

And I have a plane defined by normal vector $n$ and origin $o$.

Is there a clean mathematical representation for the evaluation of this function on the arbitrary plane? nTopology has a robust mathematics back end, and I may be able to rig together an expression that will evaluate.

Comment: Why can't you say that any plane has a form $Ax + By + Cz = D$.  Then $x,y$ are "free to roam" while $z =\dfrac{ D - By - Ax}{C}$ unless $C = 0$, but there must exist a non-zero coefficient or else $0 = 0$ is the whole dang 3D space!  So wlog, let $C \neq 0$.  That simply pass in:

$$
f(x,y,\dfrac{D - By - Ax}{C})
$$

Now use the formula that gets $A,B,C,D$ from your normal defined form.

However, it's not clean as when the plane changes, sometimes you need to parameterize in terms of $x,z$ free.  I don't know how to get over this.

Comment: @AbstractSpaceCrack how simple! Turns out this does exactly what I'm looking for. Ashamed I didn't think of this before. Now on to the next set of challenges! Edit: if you want to repost as an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Or give us your formulas.  Post them as answer and check your own answer.  Or simply delete this. :)